# RHEL6 installed wrong version of rpmforge

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm, rhel6

I installed the wrong version of rpmforge for el7. Then I ran an update which installed this package on my system

```
python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64
```

Notice the el7 but I am on rhel6. I then realized and removed the wrong repository and installed the right one for el6.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep rpmfor
rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64
```

But the above process has broken the update process, which I know I could work around using `--skip-broken` option. How do I downgrade for the above mentioned package. I tried to uninstall and install it back again but I get this error:

```
Error: Trying to remove "c4ebpl", which is protected
```

It shows me some protected packages which can't be removed.
Update process using `sudo yum update` gives me this error:

```
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@el66/$releasever)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Would anyone know how to downgrade to the original packages? Is there a way to do a factory reset? Or do I need to re-install linux again?

Some things I tried:
I deleted the `python-crypto.x86_64` package using this command

```
sudo rpm --nodeps -e python-crypto.x86_64
```

And the update went through. So I thought I should install the `python-crypto.x86_64`package now as I have the right el6 rpmforge repository. So I ran this command `sudo yum install python-crypto.x86_64` but I got the same error:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-crypto.x86_64 0:2.6.1-1.el7.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.7 for package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.10()(64bit) for package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@el66/$releasever)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-crypto-2.6.1-1.el7.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I don't know why its trying to find the el7 package? I have these libraries in my machine.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep rpmfor
rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to install the correct `rpmforge-release` package. Download it and use `rpm -U --oldpackage` to install it over the wrong package.

Second, you need to clean the cached yum metadata that it had. Use `yum clean all` to get rid of everything.

Third, use `yum distro-sync` to downgrade any packages that were installed for the wrong distribution. (And note that this will also upgrade any out-of-date packages.)

Comment: Sir you are really smart. Wow I couldn't figure that out for one whole day. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it :)